# My object is keeping its original shape aswell as adding the additional movement

Tags: modeling

I was trying to add the droop you see but the original shape was not changing when I did so. I checked and made sure I had no other duplicates and I don't.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Caught green handed. Your subdivision surface modifier is set to 0 subdivisions in the viewport (though the render levels are at 2). Also, it is animated. Right click -> clear keyframes, or any manual change will be cleared if you accidentally switch frames. [image: your subdivision levels]

Comment: and i see you are on frame 144 on the timeline, make sure you are always on frame 0 to not complicate other things

Comment: @FernaldyWiranata Correction: frame 1

Comment: Odd... i did what you said and cleared the key frames so it set to 1 level of viewport and the problem still persisted... no it isn't animated so i changed the frame to 0 as well. Anything else it could be?

Comment: @user124268 I lost track of who you’re talking to. The property was green, which means it was animated. If it is not green now then it is not animated.

Comment: ok. so it's not animated and the property is no longer green. but the problem with the mesh keeping its original shape and also adding the edit is still happenening (see the photo)

Comment: @user124268 I notice an odd fold in the icing on one drip, which makes me think something else is going on as well.

Comment: yes that's what I wanna fix is there anything that you think might be happening there?